# How do i install snowflake.sqlalchemy in anaconda?

Tags: anaconda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to connect to snowflake in Python. At present I am unsuccessful. I have read forums on using the engine way i.e.:

```
url = URL(
    account = 'xxxx',
    user = 'xxxx',
    password = 'xxxx',
    database = 'xxx',
    schema = 'xxxx',
    warehouse = 'xxx',
    role='xxxxx',
    authenticator='https://xxxxx.okta.com',
)
engine = create_engine(url)


connection = engine.connect()

query = '''
select * from MYDB.MYSCHEMA.MYTABLE
LIMIT 10;
'''

df = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
```

but I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'snowflake.sqlalchemy'
```

How do I install this module in Anaconda? I cannot find how to get round this any other way I have read does not work.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge snowflake-sqlalchemy
```

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't find anything conda related in the snowflake documentation about snowflake-sqlalchemy (only pip install).

Comment: this worked, but I also had to `pip uninstall snowflake` which was causing a conflict

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

dont use `import snowflake` together with `from snowflake.sqlalchemy`

use only;

`from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL`

Comment: How will that help if Python can't find `snowflake.sqlalchemy`?

Comment: If you already run `import snowflake`, python accept **snowflake** word as a package name and try to use it as a variable. With `from snowflake.sqlalchemy` it try to find sqlalchemy inside the snowflake library but they are totally different libraries. It happens a conflict! If you really need snowflake library, then you can use it with **as** like `import snowflake as sf`.

Comment: What I meant is that the question doesn't show what import is used and judging by the error, OP might already be doing this...

Comment: You are right @Tomerikoo . If `pip install snowflake-sqlalchemy` doesnt resolve the problem, it (conflict with **snowflake** library) can be the other reason of the problem. Just for second step...

Answer (score 1):

Even in an Anaconda environment you can use pip. Did you try `pip install snowflake-sqlalchemy`?

Comment: @d'hoeffer yes i tried that in my anaconda prompt and got error: Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/snowflake-sqlalchemy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/snowflake-sqlalchemy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)'))) - skipping . I suppose i need to get this site unblocked

Comment: Yes, sounds like it may be blocked.